# PHP String of arrays to Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mapping

I have a json that is mapped on an object. The json looks like above:

```
{
  "employeeId": "1",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "departments": [
    {
      "fieldName": "department",
      "fieldValue": "[dep1, dep2]"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to take data from "fieldValue" and put it into an array. 
`json_decode` doesn't work for me since the values inside are not quoted. It would be very helpful if I had it like `"fieldValue": "[\"dep1\",\"dep2\"]"`, but I cannot control how I receive it. Does somebody has some suggestions on how to make an array out of a string that looks like that?

Comment: json_decode() WILL work since it's a valid json structure, I just validated your json in jsonlint.com

Comment: did you tired json_decode($jsondata, true);

Comment: You could use `str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $fiedvalue)` and then `explode(', ', $fieldvalue)`. But i wont recommend this becouse it wont work on all values :p

Comment: Yes, it is a valid json, but it won't make an array from `"fieldValue": "[dep1, dep2]"` because the data in cannot be decoded. I've also tried `json_decode($jsondata, true);`

Thank you @Thaillie

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "[dev1, dev2]";
$keywords = preg_split('/[\[+\]]/', $var);
```

`$keywords[1]` will be your answer.

Then, you can split the `$keywords[1]` variable into an array using `str_split()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is good variant, but you can use json_decode function two time:

```
$json = '{
  "employeeId": "1",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "departments": [
    {
      "fieldName": "department",
      "fieldValue": "[dep1, dep2]"
    }
  ]
}';

$decodedJson = json_decode($json);
$fieldValue = json_decode(strtr($decodedJson->departments[0]->fieldValue, array(
    '[' => '["',
    ']' => '"]',
    ',' => '","'
)));
var_dump($fieldValue);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works only if the ' " ' character is escaped. Also, it is a **must** that the 'dep1', 'dep2' etc. fields should not contain the ' " ' character.